# How do I get the 3 last values between dashes in the last part of an URL

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a URL:

```
https://www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/x2-small-2
```

I'd like to extract the last part of the URL using 3 regex in Google Bigquery to get as return

- x2
- Small
- 2

This regex

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT( A.resource_data,"$.Type" ), '"(.*)"') AS model,
```

gives

```
https://www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/x2-small-2
```

As far I understand, in Bigquery it's REGEX Re2

Thanks for your help ! Sorry, I'm a newbie to regex

This regex

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT( A.resource_data,"$.Type" ), '".*/(.*)"') AS model,
```

gives

```
x2-small-2
```

I'd like at least to extract the last number (2). Any Idea ?

Comment: It's PCRE, not Perl. That's a regex engine. Has nothing to do with the Perl programming language (apart from being compatible with Perl's regexes).

Comment: Thx for the information

Comment: BigQuery regex engine is RE2. Really far from PCRE.

Comment: I don't need a complete query, but just 3 lines of regex to be integrated into my query. Thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT url,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] part1,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] part2,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] part3
FROM (
  SELECT url, SPLIT(ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(url, '/'))[OFFSET(0)], '-') parts
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'https://www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/x2-small-2' url
)
SELECT url,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] part1,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] part2,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] part3
FROM (
  SELECT url, SPLIT(ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(url, '/'))[OFFSET(0)], '-') parts
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

output is

```
Row url                                                                     part1   part2   part3    
1   https://www.example.com/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/x2-small-2    x2      small   2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last element, you use this pattern. (Sorry for the leaning toothpick syndrome, I don't know what the correct pattern building syntax in the technology you are using is).

```
/\/([^\/]+)$/
```

You will get one capture group with the whole last path part. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tm4ajD/1).

You can then break this up into smaller pieces. If it's always the same format with the three fields, you could write your pattern for that too.

```
/\/([^\/]+)-(.+)-(.+)$/
```

This will give you three capture groups. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tm4ajD/2).

Comment: Had this message for the first one : Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \/ at [8:25]
For the second one, got this when running the query : Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group.
Thank you anyway